# How can I recapture form data?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am attempting to recapture some form values after they have been posted, but am having quite a bit of difficulty. My form has 2 fields:

```
<strong>Username:</strong> <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" Width="200px" /><br /><br />
<strong>Password:</strong> <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" Width="200px" TextMode="Password" />
```

And in the code behind, I have tried to capture the username, but keep coming up empty handed. Here is my current implementation:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
        {
            txtUsername.Text = Request.Form["txtUsername"];
        }
 }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code works perfectly fine for me:

ASPX:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" 

Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="MainHTML" runat="server">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">  

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <strong>Username:</strong> <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" Width="200px" /><br /><br />
        <strong>Password:</strong> <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" Width="200px" TextMode="Password" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

cs:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
        {
            txtUsername.Text = Request.Form["txtUsername"];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all to checking if it is a post you can check with this:

```
if (IsPostback) { //do something here }
```

and you will see that if it is done on the same page will not work coz it post to itself.When you click a button in the same page data are generally saved in viewstate.So before give you more info we need to have more info about it work to better help you.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of the .aspx page, there's nothing glaringly obviously wrong there, but:

- are the TextBoxes within a form with runat="server"?
- have you run a trace to see what the Form variables, if any, contain?
- are you sure the page is being submitted, and not just refreshed?
- have you tried a breakpoint to see whether the if condition evaluates to true (similar to above point)?

Answer (score 0):

I would think you can add onclick= to the button that is submitting the form since the textboxes are running at server. After the equal sign if you press tab twice it will automatically generate an event in the code behind. Then you can do something like this in the code behind to save it in session.

```
string firstName = txtUsername.Text;
string lastName = txtPassword.Text;
Session["FirstName"] = firstName;
Session["LastName"] = lastName;
```

and to access it later

```
string firstName = Session["FirstName"];
```